# How to find the eigen value and eigen vector of matrix with size (5030 * 3 )?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have to find the eigen values of matrix which contains the 5030 rows and 3 columns. while using the numpy.linalg.eig(matrix) function it gives me error of

```
LinAlgError: Last 2 **dimensions** of the array must be square
```

is it compulsory that for eigen values matrix must be square.  or is there someways to find the eigen values of matrix with size(5030 *3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigenvalues are defined for linear endomorphisms. For that reason the associated matrix must be square in order to compute its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: thank you for reply and suggesting right answer and direction :-)